# AsyncTypeahead results are not being displayed on screen

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I have been trying to integrate the AsyncTypeahead functionality from the react-bootstrap-typeahead library. I am trying to use this with the [TheMovieDB search api](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/search/search-movies). I can see from the developer console output that I am making the api requests successfully, and the results are being passed back into to the AsyncTypeahead component, but it is saying "No matches found." on my screen.

I have copied most of the code from their github for the AsyncTypeahead implementation, and can even see the reponse results are being passed down into the options the `Typeahead` component. So I am unsure what I am missing to get them to be displayed on the screen like it is in their examples.

My search implementation component

```
import React from 'react';
import {AsyncTypeahead} from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';
import axios from 'axios';
import SearchResultMenuItem from './SearchResultMenuItem';

//Needs to be a class based component, as we have to handle state
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    state = { 
        term: '',
        options: [],
        isLoading: false
    };

    onFormSubimit = (event) => { //Arrow function makes sure the value of 'this' is always the instance of the search bar 
        event.preventDefault(); //Stops browser from submitting form automatically and refreshing the pagee
        this.props.onSubmit(this.state.term);
    }

    onHandleSearch = async (term) => {
        this.setState({isLoading: true});
        const response = await axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=c055530078ac3b21b64e0bf8a0b3b9e1&language=en-US&page=1&include_adult=false', {
            params: { query: term }
        });

        //Extract details from the search 
        const searchResults = response.data.results.map((i) => ({
            title: i.original_title,
            id: i.id,
          }));

        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            options: searchResults
        })     
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ui segment">
                <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubimit} className="ui form">
                    <div className="field">
                        <label>Image Search</label>
                        <AsyncTypeahead
                            {...this.state}
                            labelKey="original_title"
                            isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
                            onSearch={this.onHandleSearch}
                            placeholder="Enter a Movie Title..."
                            renderMenuItemChildren={(option, props) => (
                                <SearchResultMenuItem key={option.id} item={option} />
                              )}
                        />
                    </div>                    
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

My SearchResultMenuItem component

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

const SearchResultMenuItem = ({item}) => (
    <div>
        <img
            style={{
                height: '24px',
                marginRight: '10px',
                width: '24px',
            }}
        />
        <span>{item.original_title}</span>
  </div>
);

SearchResultMenuItem.propTypes = {
    item: PropTypes.shape({
        original_title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
};

export default SearchResultMenuItem;
```

**Expected Results**

I expect a list of movie names to be shown as options to choose, that come from the response from the query of TheMovieDB's api.

**Actual Results**

The UI simple displays a *No matches found* message on the screen.

I get a warning message on the console saying *Warning: [react-bootstrap-typeahead] The prop `id` is required to make `Menu` accessible for users of assistive technologies such as screen readers.* I have tried googling this, but have not found any solutions.

**See below for screenshots from the developer console**
[image: Warning message]

[image: Developer console output]

You can see results from the search api in the *options* array above

**Update UI After Fix**

[image: Update UI]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please use `labelKey="title"` in AsyncTypeahead since your options object has title.Also, in SearchResultMenuItem change `<span>{item.title}</span>`, also change the props as well `title: PropTypes.string.isRequired`. This should resolve the issue. Also, to remove the id warning just provide a unique id name to AsyncTypeahead component like `id="some_unique_id"` (it can be any random id)

Comment: That has worked. Thanks a lot! Only thing is the suggestions don't look like the ones in the demo. Any idea why that might be? I've updated my question with a screenshot

Comment: I actually resolved this by adding the bootstrap css to the project. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure about the demo,  but the api doc tells about the label key conventions https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/Data.md

Comment: Hi @Eoin, Can we handle 'No matched Found' option ,can we custom with our own Option box.with the default styles??

Answer (score 0):

Check if the array exists before setting the value, something like this

```
 onInputChange={(v) => {
      if (v.length) {
        console.log(v, "KDDDDDDDK");
        setValue(v[0]);
      }
    }}
```

---